# Remove separator (border) of 'tabs'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design

Can the border be removed from the unanswered tab? It should only be displayed as a separator between the tabs IMHO.

[image: border]

Comment: I was going to say that it acts like a shadow, (and therefore would seem intentional) but the "shadow" is not duplicated for "Ask Question" so consistency would be preferable, either way.

Comment: OTOH as the background to Unanswered is similar to the header background it might get a little lost, so I'd prefer that Ask Question had a shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed; this looks better now. The shadow is still there, but it gets lighter when the button gets lighter.

Comment: Thanks. Much better.