# Border styling of tabs on hover

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design

The (color of the) border of the selected tabs [has been changed](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/647/remove-separator-border-of-tabs). However is still see a minor (related) issue. When a tab is active (on page of the tab), the tab gets a light background. However when hovering over the active tab the border still change to a lighter border. It may be pretty hard to notice, but now that I have seen it it cannot be unseen.

I suggest that the active tab always has the lighter border (same color color as on hover).

**EDIT**

As requested a screenshot:

[image: border color]

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. Could you provide a screenshot indicating the issue? Also, could you include browser and OS info?

Comment: @Aarthi screenshot uploaded. It's a screen from Meta, but the same happens on main. Regarding the browser and OS -> doesn't matter.

Comment: I've passed this along. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue with the specificity of the CSS rules. Fixed in the next build of the site.